# Синоним к слову "любовь"

Tags: синонимы

Пытаюсь подобрать адекватный синоним к слову "любовь". То ли туплю сегодня, то ли его действительно подобрать сложно.
Просто наткнулась на такой вопрос в сети случайно и задумалась. А какое слово может стать достаточно адекватным синонимом? Расположение? Приязнь? Страсть? Хорошее отношение? Но это все не любовь.
Может кому-то удастся придумать что-то лучшее.

Comment: Обожание -вот самый подходящий синоним для слова "любовь"

Comment: Амор - и глазами так...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Обожание -вот самый подходящий синоним для слова "любовь"

**Обожание** — это возведение в ранг божества. Создание кумира. Что со временем ведёт к **разочарованию**. Потому что, как правило, объект поклонения в действительности не так идеален, как представлялось.

> Расположение? Приязнь? Страсть? Хорошее отношение?

Любовь бывает разная. Страсть и обожание по юности и неопытности кажутся привлекательными, особенно барышням, — чтобы всю душу выворачивало и выматывало... Фейерверк эмоций и в голове словно опьянение.

А потом со временем можно прийти к пониманию, что *приязнь* и *хорошее отношение* — это что-то более ценное. Когда человека понимают и видят с его недостатками и тем не менее **любят** за его **действительные достоинства**.

*Страсть* — вспышка, как взрыв, который может и преграду на дороге снести, а может и бед натворить. От неё может быть плохо. И пройти может быстро.
*Приязнь* — как тёплая и уютная печка, от которой хорошо.

Так что слово *любовь* в русском языке может по смыслу означать довольно разные вещи. И синоним в каждом случае потребуется соответствующий.

Answer (score 3):

У слова любовь нет синонима. Слова нежность, страсть, расположение и т.д и т.п - это лишь духовное и физическое составляющие этого понятия. Единственный более-менее близкий синоним из всех этих составляющих, как отметил [[@Виктор](/users/895/%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%801799)](/users/895/%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%801799), - обожание.

Answer (score 2):

Согласно этимологии, в основе слова "любовь" лежит предпочтение, выбор предмета обожания,  а страстная к нему привязанность – это последующее расширение значения, что вполне соответствует действительному развитию событий. Ближайшие  родственники слова  – это «любой» и «либо» (прежнее «любо»).

Синоним современному слову «любовь»  подобрать сложно, так как это  неразделимое сочетание  различных чувств: влечение, привязанность, страсть, вожделение, обожание, влюбленность. Но можно воспользоваться описанием: нежная страсть, нежное чувство,  сердечная склонность. Или перейти на латынь, например:

"В 1995 году он побывал в Москве, и все его многочисленные поклонницы увидели своего идола «живьем»: он быстр, элегантен, сладкозвучен, женщины, особенно бальзаковского возраста, от него тихо млеют ― амор, амор!"

Answer (score 2):

Под словом "любовь" в русском языке подразумеваются в зависимости от контекста разные вещи, поэтому для разных видов любви существуют разные синонимы.

**Любовь плотская**. Тут особых проблем с синонимами нет: *секс, трахание, адюльтер* и др.
**Любовь материальная** (к науке, к вещам). В этом случае почти всегда "любовь" можно заменить словом *страсть*.
**Любовь Бога** в православии можно заменить словом *благодать*.
**Любовь романтическая** имеет синонимами слова: *амуры, шуры-муры, сохнуть*.
А вот к **любви родственной** (любовь матери, сына брата), мне найти подходящего синонима-слова не удалось, но можно заменить выражением *тёплые чувства*.

Answer (score 0):

"Проникновенн(-ость) (-ые чувства)" в несколько переосмысленном варианте как метафизический синоним.

Answer (score 0):

По идее, слово "милость" ― близкое к *любовь* ("милый мой", миловаться ― любоваться).

В этом плане само понятие "помиловать" обретает интересный подтекст: не только привычное нам "простить", "пощадить", а и полюбить.

В польском "милошч", кажется, и значит любовь.